# Pig and sequence files

Tags: apache-pig

I need to write a script that loads a few sequence files and merges them to one big sequence file and stores the file. Problem is i could not find any store or load functions that deal with sequence file. I am lost on how to do this. Advice would be helpful.

Comment: language? what have you tried so far?

Comment: In pig of course. I didnt try anythhing because i didnt find any store or load functions as i said that deal with sequence files...

Comment: http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/how-to-read-contents-of-a-sequencefile-in-pig-generated-by-sqoop-import/

Comment: I couldnt find how to store it

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/pull/73